# FF: debugging places.sqlite - logging of different visit_type

Tags: sqlite, firefox

i have a question concerning the history file places.sqlite. It's a sqlite file containing several tables. My question concerns the table moz_historyvisits. It has a column "visit_type", which is well explained here:
http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox_3_History_File_Format#moz_historyvisits .

I can read places.sqlite e.g. with "SQLiteBrowser" under Windows. 
If i visit a page using the history (visit_type = 2), in places.sqlite each visit is stored. That means if i click the link several times in a short period, each click is recorded in places.sqlite.
If i click the SAME URL using a link in the webpage (visit_type = 1) itself several times in a short period, only the first click is recorded in the places.sqlite.

The requests are in both cases identical, i can check it with our own webserver.
Con someone confirm this behaviour ? Does anyone know why it is like this ?
Thanks.

I'm using FF 46.0.1 on Windows 7 64bit.

Bernd

Comment: link is down but still a useful resource, use https://web.archive.org/web/20190311213625/http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox_3_History_File_Format

Answer (score 0):

I think it is explained on the page you linked to:

> 1 TRANSITION_LINK This transition type means the user followed a link and got a new toplevel window.

When you click a link inside the page that refers back to itself several times, then you do not get a *new toplevel window* every time.

The top level window stays the same, and therefor of those repeated link clicks, only the first one is counted/recorded.